# Android Nullpointer Exception onQueryTextChange when switch fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, searchview

I have the following problem:

When I switch from fragment1 to fragment2 I get a nullpointer exception.
fragment2 has a searchview with a filter. Error occurs of some mobile pones and I dont know why.

The app crashed in mListAdapter.getFilter().filter there:

```
        @Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    lv.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

    return false;
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.kansosystem.fragments.FragmentList.onQueryTextChange(FragmentList.java:291)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1154)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.SearchView.access$2000(SearchView.java:92)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.SearchView$11.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1623)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3280)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:11910)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11888)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.restoreActionViewStates(MenuBuilder.java:358)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:417)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2595)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.invalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1950)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:901)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.kansosystem.fragments.FragmentList.onCreate(FragmentList.java:53)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-25 09:18:25.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1430):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Either `mListAdapter` or `getFilter()` returns null

Comment: If the list adapter reference is comming from the other activity is very probable you will get null when using it. getFilter() following the documentation is not supposed to return null if your mListAdapter is not null.

Comment: I dont think it is the mListAdapter. OnCreateView there is a checkback if the adapter exist, when it doesnt exist, it creates one.

Comment: Well, you don't have more code there that can lead to a null pointer exception than the mListAdapter. If the line 291 is "mListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);" you can be sure it's a problem with the mListAdapter.

Comment: Ok i checked the adapter if null and it is null. Very strange, i check the code and write back later, if it works. thx

Comment: getFilter() is a method implemented by adapter based objects like ArrayAdapter, so it wont return a null reference to Filter. filter() is an implemented method of the Filter that the ArrayAdapter has to create for you when you call getFilter(), so its not either the problem. And I doubt you are receiving a null string from onQueryTextChange callback, and in that case the exception would be different.

Comment: the bug is fixed. It was the Adapter = null, i made a checkback if adapter != null for getfilter part. thanks for the help

Comment: Just change your `onCreateOptionMenu` code to `onPrepareOptionMenu`

Comment: @SimonGlox hye there , can u show how you removed this error coz  i am still getting this error. on changing orientation in app.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your adapter is not `null`. You can do that simply by having a log like

```
Log.d("tag","mListAdapter="+mListAdapter);
mListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
```

then check logcat to see if `mListAdapter` gives `mListAdapter=null`. If so then problem is your adapter.

Second, go to your `getfilter` method in Custom listadapter class and make sure your filter doesn't return `null`. It **must** return your filter.